# Parametrization of an intersection

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hello I'm trying to parametrize the intersection of the sphere of centre $(0,0,0)$ and radius $R$ and the cylinder of centre $(R/2,0,0)$ and radius $R/2$. (the intersection is the surface)

Any hints of how to proceed? My guess is to switch into cylinder coordinates but I can't figure out what value I have to put for my $z$ coordinate. I don't understand the concept of parametrization very well, any comment is welcome.

Comment: Care to tell us the direction of the axis of the cylinder? Frieder seems to have guessed that it is in the direction of the $z$-axis. If you are happy with his guess, then that's fine. Just remember next time that even though we are very good at such guessing games, it cannot hurt to describe the geometric object fully!

Comment: Ok I'll try to be more careful next time, I'm kind of new here. Thanks anyway

Comment: No real harm was done :-). Hope you enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your equations:
$${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = {R^2}$$
$${\left( {x - \frac{R}{2}} \right)^2} + {y^2} = {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}$$
Indroducing:
$$\begin{gathered}
  x = \frac{R}{2}(\cos (\varphi ) + 1) \hfill \\
  y = \frac{R}{2}\sin (\varphi ) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
the second equation is satisfied.
From first equation now you get:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {\left( {\frac{R}{2}(\cos (\varphi ) + 1)} \right)^2} + {\left( {\frac{R}{2}\sin (\varphi )} \right)^2} + {z^2} = {R^2} \hfill \\
  {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}({\cos ^2}(\varphi ) + 2cos(\varphi ) + 1) + {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}{\sin ^2}(\varphi ) + {z^2} = {R^2} \hfill \\
  {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}{\sin ^2}(\varphi ) + {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}{\cos ^2}(\varphi ) + 2{\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}cos(\varphi ) + {\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2} + {z^2} = {R^2} \hfill \\
  2{\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}(cos(\varphi ) + 1) + {z^2} = {R^2} \hfill \\
  {z^2} = {R^2} - 2{\left( {\frac{R}{2}} \right)^2}(cos(\varphi ) + 1) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
With $0 \leqslant \varphi  < 2\pi $

$$\begin{gathered}
  x = \frac{R}{2}(\cos (\varphi ) + 1) \hfill \\
  y = \frac{R}{2}\sin (\varphi ) \hfill \\
  z =  \pm \frac{{R\sqrt {1-\cos (\varphi )} }}{{\sqrt 2 }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
is given the parametrization, that describes two surfaces bounded by magenta coloured curve. We used cylindric parametrization.
For $R=1$ picture shows upper half.
[image]